# Strange next.js error in production: ENOENT: No such file or directory (image cache)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, deployment, next.js

I'm having issues with my next.js deployment on AWS EC2. I `npm run build` and then `npm run start`, and it works fine. At that point, there are no webp images in the cache, as expected. Then I load the webpage from my browser ,and it works fine. However it randomly seems to crash when i load the page sometimes. And i get the error above. It seems like the webp image is being deleted from the cache at some point, and causing an error? Any suggestions?

The full error is:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ec2-user/prowash/pro-wash-site/.next/cache/images/7P-NdCEO6XWRTvqPItIV6CN1db-7IkBJw9kp3M5VafQ=/0.1647390677641.UEF7UxgKHha+us8b5ahYFWZH70qZHTAu2uyVPlYT7Hs=.webp'
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/ec2-user/prowash/pro-wash-site/.next/cache/images/7P-NdCEO6XWRTvqPItIV6CN1db-7IkBJw9kp3M5VafQ=/0.1647390677641.UEF7UxgKHha+us8b5ahYFWZH70qZHTAu2uyVPlYT7Hs=.webp'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use a build script to set the permissions and then implement the next build.

Modifying the solution for EBS via this [article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-make-next-js-image-optimization-work-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-2776ea255eff):

1. A Build.sh script that sets permissions before its deployed

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status
set -e


# building the Next.js application
npm run next:build

# creating the build/cache/images folder and give it
# the read/write permissions
mkdir -p .next/cache/images
chmod -R 666 .next/cache/images
```

2. Addition to `package.json` to make sure it runs on `npm run build`

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "./build.sh"
}
```